# python selenium, cant retrieve text of xpath

Tags: python, html, selenium, nested

Im struggling with scraping a few pages ... it happens when the structure of the page implies a lot of nested divs...
Here is the code page:

```
<div>
            <section class="ui-accordion-header ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-accordion-icons" role="tab" id="ui-id-1" aria-controls="ui-id-2" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0"><span class="ui-accordion-header-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e"></span>
                <div class="detail-avocat">
                    <div class="nom-avocat">Me <span class="avocat_name">NAME </span></div>
                                            <div class="type-avocat">Avocat postulant au Tribunal Judiciaire</div>
                                                        </div>
                <div class="more-info">Plus d'informations</div>
            </section>
            <div class="ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" style="display: none;" id="ui-id-2" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="details">
                    <div class="detail-avocat-row ">
                        <div class="detail-avocat-content overflow-h">
                            <span>Structure :</span> 
                            <div>
                                <p>Cabinet individuel NAME</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="detail-avocat-row ">
                        <div class="detail-avocat-content overflow-h">
                            <span>Adresse :</span> 
                            <div>
                                 <p>21 rue Belle Isle   57000 VILLE</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="detail-avocat-row ">
                        <div class="detail-avocat-content overflow-h">
                            <span>Mail :</span> 
                            <div>
                                <p>cabinet@mail.fr</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="detail-avocat-row">
                        <div class="detail-avocat-content overflow-h">
                            <span>Tél :</span> 
                            <div>
                                <p>Telnum</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="detail-avocat-row">
                        <div class="detail-avocat-content overflow-h">
                            <span>Fax :</span> 
                            <div>
                                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                                            <div class="contact-avocat"> <a href="mailto:cabinet@mail.fr">Contacter</a> </div>
                        
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And here is my python code:

```
divtel = self.driver.find_elements(by=By.XPATH,
                                              value=f'//div[@class="detail-avocat-content overflow-h"]/div/p')#div[@class="detail-avocat-content overflow-h"]')
for p in divtel:
    print(p.text)
```

It doesnt print anything...with other similar pages it prints the text but in this case it doesnt altough there is text in the nested span and div/p . Do you know why?

How can i resolve my problem please?
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `.text` works only when the webelement containing the text is visible in the webpage. If otherwise the webelement is hidden, you have to use `.get_attribute('innerText')` or `.get_attribute('textContent')` or `.get_attribute('innerHTML')` (see [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_innertext.asp) for difference between them). So for example change

```
print(p.text)
```

to

```
print(p.get_attribute('innerText'))
```

Comment: thanks! do you know why it also doesnt find the hidden element? when i do self.driver.find_elements and i provide the nested div in the xpath, the resulting list is sometimes empty...

Comment: @kr1p could you provide the specific xpath giving you an empty result?

Comment: find_elements(by=By.XPATH,value=f'//input[@id="_ctl0_Corps_txtRSNom"]') at https://www.avocatparis.org/annuaire for example. it is inside a table/tr/td but it doesnt retrieve it...even when i copy xpath in firefox (//*[@id="_ctl0_Corps_txtRSNom"]) it doesnt find it